# Check text box for spaces

Tags: php

I need help with code to output an error if a text box contains a space or hyphen.  I have the following:

```
elseif($_REQUEST['students']['FIRST_NAME']!= "CONTAINS SPACE OR HYPHENS")
{
    $insert_error = 'No spaces, hyphens, or spaces allowed in first name';
}
```

What function could I use?  I have other functions that work for similar tasks such as:

```
elseif($_REQUEST['students']['PASSWORD']!=$_REQUEST['verify_password'])
{
    $insert_error = 'Passwords did not match.';
}
```

I know it's quite straight forward, but I'm not sure what to use.  Forgive me, I'm very rusty.

Comment: You could use regular expressions. But I can't say more because I'm not used to using regexp with php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regular expressions and the `preg_match()` function.

```
if ( preg_match('/[\s-]/', $_REQUEST['students']['FIRST_NAME']) ) {
  $insert_error = 'You cannot enter spaces or dashes';
}
```

The `[\s-]` inside of `preg_match()` is called a regular expression. The `\s` is for any whitespace character, and the  `-` is for the dash.

More information here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score -2):

```
$first_name = $_REQUEST['students']['FIRST_NAME'];
elseif((preg_match("/\\s/", $first_name) === true)
")
{
    $insert_error = 'No spaces, hyphens, or spaces allowed in first name';
}
```